# firebase (Javascript) onMessage not firing

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Google's quickstart-js messaging project, yet the onMessage function isn't firing at-all. I've tried several things I've found on here (closing/opening firefox and such).

Background worker works just fine, foreground doesn't react at all. Any ideas?

[Firebase Messaging quickstart-js on github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/bf572867dbaf29bb78aa3b5fe5f0c1a6f282f96e/messaging)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get rid of this bug by updating the importScripts in firebase-messaging-sw.js to the same version used in index.html, specifically to this:

```
importScripts('/__/firebase/7.3.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/7.3.0/firebase-messaging.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/init.js');
```

I will also post an issue on their github page so they update it.